# How to get docker containers on separate hosts to share a volume?

Tags: docker, node-red

Docker n00b here. I have conatinerized programs running on two different physical computers. on '200', I have node-red, deepstack, mosquito, etc. on '199', I have iSpy (NVR) plus a couple others. I have installed docker swarm, and I am using portainer as a front end. Portainer renders the manager and worker just fine and it seems the swarm is working. Here's the problem I cant figure out:

I need Node-red (on '200') to read a file that is saved on '199', then pass it through deepstack and do a bunch of other things, but I cant for the life of me figure out how to get node-red to read from the other physical machine. I figure if I can get some kind of persistent volume that is shared between all the different containers, I should be good, but when I create a container, it can only be seen by the host its on (not the other one). In other words, I can create a voilume on '200' and have node-red and deepstack see the same files, but ispy (on '199') doesnt even have the option of mounting that same volume.

So....what am I missing. I KNOW there is an easy solution, but I cant seem to find it.

Any help would be appreciatted.

I have tried to connect them using a single internal net5work (through Docker Swarm), but Node-red doesnt seem to want to see the other machine when I use the internal ip for it.

I tried to create a persistent volume and attach it to the several docker containers, but it seems the volumes can only be connected to the containers that are on the same host

I tried to bind to folders outside of docker and then samba share them across the home network, but node-red wouldnt see that folder when using the ip address of the smb share.

Comment: Take a look at _Technique #2: Sharing Data Over NFS_ section at https://devm.io/docker/how-to-share-docker-volumes-across-hosts-119602

Comment: Do you actually need real files for this?  Or can you use stateless containers that send data back and forth using things like HTTP connections?

Comment: If you just need to read the file from the other system, one easy way to do it would be to copy the file over ssh using scp. Just need to configure openssh in your node-red container.

You can use an exec node to run the command "scp user@target_ip_address:/path/to/target/file /destination/path" and if you have an ssh key stored on your target system then this will work without any password prompt.

You can also make changes to your local copy and send them back to the original system with another scp